# Перегрузить операцию ввода для типа vector

Tags: c++

Подскажите как правильно нужно перегрузить операцию ввода для записи в файл.

```
#include <iostream>
using std::ofstream;
using std::ifstream;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
using std::ios;

#include <fstream>

#include <vector>
using std::vector;

#include "stdio.h"

class Number {
    friend ifstream &operator>>(ifstream &in, Number &ob);
    friend ofstream &operator<<(ofstream &out, vector<Number> &ob);
public:
    Number(int _x1 = 0, int _x2 = 0)
        :x1(_x1), x2(_x2) {}    

    void show() const;
private:
    int x1, x2;
};

int main()
{
    setlocale(NULL, "RUS"); 

    ofstream outFile("file.txt",ios::out);

    if (!outFile) {
        cout << "Файл невозможно открыть.";
        return 1;
    }

    vector<Number> list;

    for (size_t i = 1; i < 10; i++)
        list.push_back(Number(i, pow(i,2));

    outFile << list;    

    outFile.close();    

    return 0;
}

ifstream & operator>>(ifstream & in, Number & ob)
{
    in >> ob.x1;
    in >> ob.x2;        

    return in;
}

ofstream & operator<<(ofstream & out, vector<Number>& ob)
{
    for (static size_t i = 0; i < ob.size(); ++i)
        out << ob;

    return out;
}

void Number::show() const
{
    cout << x1 << ' ' << x2;
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Как я понял `ofstream & operator<<(ofstream & out, vector<Number>& ob)` рекурсивная.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно сразу сделать шаблонном:

```
template<typename T>
std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &stream, std::vector<T> &result)
{
    T number;
    while (stream >> number) {//читаем до первой ошибки ввода
        result.push_back(number);
    }
    return stream;
}

template<typename T>
std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &stream, const std::vector<T> &source)
{
    for (auto &&e: source) {
        stream << e << ' ';
    }
    return stream;
}
```

Comment: Я извиняюсь, но я не правильно написал заголовок. Я хотел перегрузить эту функцию `ofstream & operator<<(ofstream & out, vector<Number>& ob)`

Comment: Не могли бы Вы объяснить ` for (auto &&e: source)`, а точнее про auto

Comment: ofstream потомок ostream, потому достаточно перегружать  так как вам ответили